# Google Script: getText() is not getting 'span' element

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This is the variable:

```
var buffer = <h1>Company Overview of <span itemprop="name">Citrix Systems, Inc.</span></h1>
```

This is how I parse it:

```
var parsed = Xml.parse(buffer).getElement().getText();
```

This returns:

```
Company Overview of
```

How can I get this?

```
Company Overview of Citrix Systems, Inc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it now:

```
var parsed = XmlService.parse(buffer).getRootElement().getValue();
```